# Rigify Is Improperly Deforming Model (I think)

Tags: modeling, rigging, bones, weight-painting, rigify

I found [a tutorial](https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/tutorials/rigging-minutes-blenders-rigify-addon) on how to use the rigify add-on, and now my mesh is pulling with my bone. I am new, but am sure that a more experienced person would be able to solve this problem.

Before rotate
[image: T-pose]

After rotate
[image: rotation of the arm]

**Update**: I unparented the meta rig and parented the rig. And yes, I did use armature deform *With Automatic Weights*, so if that is the issue then I can look up how to weight paint.

Comment: Which tutorial was this? You are using the *metarig* for animation. This is *not* the purpose of it. Look for Rigify's *Generate Rig* button and use it to generate the animation rig (*rig*). Clear Parent first (Alt+P) to un-parent the metarig & make sure the *Armature* modifier is gone, then bind the mesh to the generated rig (Ctrl+P). It has a better deformation, lot more controls & switches, IK and FK, and other features.

Comment: Hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Looks like incorrect weights to me. I suppose you parented the mesh to the armature using "Armature Deform with *automatic weights*"? This is nice to make an initial weight job, but often requires touching up, precisely to avoid this kind of things.

Comment: My tutorial is this: https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/tutorials/rigging-minutes-blenders-rigify-addon. Also, I unparented the meta rig and parented the rig.  I uploaded the file but without my subdivision modifier. And yes, I did use armature deform with automatic weights, so if that is the issue then I can look up how to weight paint.

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial link. If you have uploaded your file to blend-exchange.com you need to post the link that is displayed after the upload, otherwise nobody can access the file.